# python copy files based on regex pattern via shutil

Tags: python, regex, shutil

I am new at stackoverflow as well as programming and I am trying to solve a rather time-consuming problem in the office. We would like to copy files based on their filename to a different location or add them to a .zip file.

The filename looks like this 16410_REC-**7372**-20201102161426.PDF.

The important parts are:

- we need to select only files that contain the prefix 'REC'
- the following 4 digits are the numeric range of desired documents which will need to be specified by user input
- finally, the files that fall within the numeric range need to be copied to a new destination or alternatively added to a .zip file

The only thing I got working so far is to copy files based on the file ending to another location. From what I've read this could be done with regex (the string I think I could construct) but I am missing how to implement the selection in python.

Here is the code so far:

```
from os.path import isfile
import os
import shutil

source = os.listdir("n:/DIESTEIN/DSCS/Dokumente/")
destination = "n:/Test/"

print('select starting number: ')
f_start = input()

print('select ending number: ')
f_end = input()

for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.copy(files, destination)
```

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction or help me writing the code?

Cheers,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look for a static pattern, you don't really need regular expressions.

As an aside, I would change your script to simply look in the current directory; then it's easy to test on a set of files you want to test on without having to experiment with the real production location.

```py
# from os.path import isfile  <- unused, comment out
import os
import shutil

destination = "n:/Test/"

f_start = int(input('select starting number: '))
f_end = int(input('select ending number: '))

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if "_REC-" in file and f_start <= int(file.split("-")[1]) <= f_end:
        shutil.copy(file, destination)
```

If you really wanted to use regular expressions, maybe something along the lines of

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\d+_REC-(\d+)-\d+\.PDF")
...
    matching = pattern.match(file)
    if matching and f_start <= int(matching.group(1)) <= f_end:
```

The regex imposes a stricter check on whether the file name matches the expected pattern (where of course I had to guess what exactly you expect). If you have files which contain `_REC-` but don't adhere to the pattern, maybe a regex would be useful. But for simple requirements, it's easier to see what the code does if you just pick apart the file name enough to extract the parts you need, and then you don't have to learn to read regex just yet.  (For example, if it's not quite strict enough, maybe also check if the file name starts with a number and ends with `.PDF`?)

Notice also how we need to convert strings containing numbers to `int` in order to perform numeric comparisons. (If you forget, `"123"` will seem to be "smaller" than `"22"` because `1` comes before `2` alphabetically.)